# RDS(PostgreSQL)に接続できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-rds

EC2上でマイグレーションを実行しようとしたところRDS（PostgreSQL）への接続ができず失敗します。一週間ほどここでつまづいております。

エラーコード：

```
[yuki@ip-10-0-0-152 golfour]$ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=productionrake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "yuki" does not exist
/home/yuki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/yuki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "yuki" does not exist
/home/yuki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/yuki/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

RDSへの接続は以下の方法では確認できるのですが、マイグレーションできない理由がわかりません。
何かあればご教授願います。

```
[yuki@ip-10-0-0-152 golfour]$ psql --host=golfour-postgresql.cu0oqputapjt.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --dbname=postgres --username=yuki --dbname=golfour_production
ユーザ yuki のパスワード: 
psql (11.5、サーバ 11.6)
SSL 接続 (プロトコル: TLSv1.2、暗号化方式: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384、ビット長: 256、圧縮: オフ)
"help" でヘルプを表示します。

golfour_production=>   

[yuki@ip-10-0-0-152 golfour]$ systemctl status postgresql.service● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 水 2020-08-05 06:49:07 UTC; 17h ago
 Main PID: 5698 (postmaster)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
           ├─5698 /usr/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
           ├─5701 postgres: logger   
           ├─5703 postgres: checkpointer   
           ├─5704 postgres: background writer   
           ├─5705 postgres: walwriter   
           ├─5706 postgres: autovacuum launcher   
           ├─5707 postgres: stats collector   
           └─5708 postgres: logical replication launcher
```

開発環境：
Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.4.3
Amazon Linux2

追記：ロール一覧

```
[yuki@ip-10-0-0-152 ~]$ psql --host=golfour-postgresql.cu0oqputapjt.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --dbname=postgres --username=yuki --dbname=golfour_production
ユーザ yuki のパスワード: 
psql (11.5、サーバ 11.6)
SSL 接続 (プロトコル: TLSv1.2、暗号化方式: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384、ビット長: 256、圧縮: オフ)
"help" でヘルプを表示します。

golfour_production=> \du
                                                                         ロール一覧
    ロール名     |                                    属性                                    |                        所属グループ                 
        
-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
--------
 rds_ad          | ログインできません                                                         | {}
 rds_iam         | ログインできません                                                         | {}
 rds_password    | ログインできません                                                         | {}
 rds_replication | ログインできません                                                         | {}
 rds_superuser   | ログインできません                                                         | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_pa
ssword}
 rdsadmin        | スーパーユーザ, ロール作成可, DB作成可, レプリケーション可, RLS のバイパス+| {}
                 | パスワードの有効期限 infinity                                              | 
 rdsrepladmin    | 継承なし, ログインできません, レプリケーション可                           | {}
 yuki            | ロール作成可, DB作成可                                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | パスワードの有効期限 infinity                                              |
```

Comment: PostgreSQLのroleの設定周りはどうなっていますか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
roleの設定周りを質問内容の最後に追記しました。

`role "yuki" does not exist`
とエラーでは書かれているのですが、roleにはyukiがあるのでなぜ？となっています。そもそものRDSとの接続がおかしいのでしょうか。